# Margins are not updated in the document

Tags: margins, memoir

I used my university thesis class to complete my dissertation. However, my university requires margins to be 1.5 inches on the left and 1 inch on the right, top, and bottom of the page. I have tried changing them in the .cls file, but I don't see them updated on the document. I have copied the part of the .cls file where the margins are declared.

```
\LoadClass{memoir}

\RequirePackage{calc}

% command for optional typesetting
\newcommand{\pretty}[1]{}
\if@pretty\renewcommand{\pretty}[1]{#1}\fi

%set the margins
%\RequirePackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry} 
%\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setheaderspaces{*}{\baselineskip}{*}
\newlength{\@extrafootskip}
\settoheight{\@extrafootskip}{1}
\setheadfoot{.5in}{.5in}%-\@extrafootskip}
\setmarginnotes{10pt}{1in}{1ex}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%modify the above lengths to account for the margins
\newlength{\@topmatter}\setlength{\@topmatter}{1in}
\newlength{\@bottommatter}\setlength{\@bottommatter}{1in}
\setlength{\@topmatter}{\uppermargin}
\addtolength{\@topmatter}{\headsep}
\addtolength{\@bottommatter}{\lowermargin}
```

I am still getting all sides' margins to be 1 inch. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Te.SE community!

Comment: Are you saying that your university thesis class does not produce margins accepted by your university?  Interesting!  Maybe they want oneside pages.

Answer (score 1):

- It is not entirely clear what you like to get.
- Page layout in `memoir` document you can be simple defined for example with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openbib,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}  
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{247mm}{120mm}{*}%237
\setulmargins{25mm}{*}{1}           % upper, lower margin, ratio
\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{60mm}{*}% spinner, outer margin, ratio
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{45mm}{2.5mm}
\checkandfixthelayout
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
page layout
\end{document}
```

(example is taken from one of my textbook).

- I must confess that I'm lost in your code example, so I'm not able to insert your desired text block and margins size.
- For more details about setting of page layout see package documentation.

[image]